# Getting 500 while adding data to datatables in javascript .net mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

So i'm trying to add data to datatable, i'm relatively new to Web Applications, i'm more of a mobile app developer
I've looked into a few examples and i've come up with a solution to do it, but for some reason i'm getting this error on chrome

> DataTables warning: table id=personaliseDatatable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

And if i check the console i'm getting Internal Server Error 500, but in fact the controller is getting triggered and i'm able to get the data from the repository, but its not able to return is what i'm able to understand

This is my method in controller

```
  public JsonResult GetAllCapacityData()
    {
        try
        {
            var data = _capacityService.GetAllData(null).ToList();

            return Json(new
            {
                data = data
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("WebApp -> AreaMappingController -> GetAllData -> Catch  -> ", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

and this is my ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if ($('#loaderDiv').hasClass("show")) {
      $('#loaderDiv').removeClass("show");
   }
   GetCapacityData();
});

function GetCapacityData() {
   $('#personaliseDatatable').DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      processing: false,
      serverSide: false,
      searching: true,
      scrollX: true,
      bDestroy: true,
      "scrollX": true,
      aaSorting: [0, 'desc'],
      ajax: {
         url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCapacityData", "Capacity")',
         type: 'POST'
      },
      language: {
         search: "",
         searchPlaceholder: "Search...",
         sInfoFiltered: ""
      },
      columns: [{
            "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
               return meta.row + 1;
            }
         },
         {
            data: "data.ZoneMaster.ZoneName"
         },
         {
            data: "CateogoryName"
         },
         {
            data: "SubCateogoryName"
         },
         {
            data: "ServiceType"
         },
         {
            data: "UserType"
         },
         {
            data: "Division"
         },
         {
            data: "SlotName"
         },
         {
            data: "AllowBooking"
         },
         {
            data: "HoursBlockAhead"
         },
         {
            data: "DaysOpenAheadForBooking"
         },
         {
            data: "MaximumOrderCapacity"
         },
         {
            mRender: function(data, type, row) {
               return '<a  class="actionLinks" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View Details" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="EditCapacity(' + row.CapacityPlannerId + ')">Edit</a>';
            },
            sortable: false,
            searchable: false
         }
      ]

   });

   alert(data.ZoneMaster.ZoneId);
}
```

And this my Datatable

```
        <div class="card-body">
            <table style="width:100%" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="personaliseDatatable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Zone</th>
                        <th>Cateogory</th>
                        <th>Sub Cateogory</th>
                        <th>Service Type</th>
                        <th>User Type</th>
                        <th>Division</th>
                        <th>Slot Name</th>
                        <th>Allow Booking</th>
                        <th>Hours to Block Ahead</th>
                        <th>Days Open Ahead</th>
                        <th>Max. Order Capacity</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Error on console

> POST http://localhost:53201/Capacity/GetAllCapacityData 500 (Internal Server Error)

Any Help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Your `GetAllCapacityData` looks like it expects to be GETted but you POST to it? What's the point of the POST if you don't handle whatever is POSTed?

Comment: yea but i can use it either way right?, ideally it should be able to return me the data, i mean i am able to get to the endpoint

Comment: 500 should be either caught in your try-catch (is it?) or at least logged in the system's event log. Check these two to find the actual exception. Come back with your findings.

Comment: tried using the error function in ajax, found out that it has cyclic problem while serializing